# How to show table view cell index path and collection View Index path at the same time in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Can anyone help me that how to show index path both table view and collection view index. In my case table view cell contain many collection view cell. And collection view cell contains one button when user pressed the button an alert show which show the pressed button from table view index (i.e 2) and collection view index (i.e 4).

Problem is that it show Collection View cell Index Path properly but don't show Table View Cell index Path.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
      //MARK:- Variable Declaration
    
    let arryOfCollectionCell = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
    
    let arryOfTableCell = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

//MARK:- Table View


extension ViewController:  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return arryOfTableCell.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? CellForTableView else { return }

        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)
          
    }
    
    
}

//MARK:- Collection View

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
           numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

           return arryOfCollectionCell.count
       }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
     
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CellForCollectionView
        
        cell.myButtonTapAction = { cell in

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You Got it !", message: "Selected Index Path Number is \(indexPath[1])", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        
        return cell
    }
   
}
```

Here is my Collection View Cell:

```
import UIKit

class CellForCollectionView: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var clickBtnOut: UIButton!
    
     var myButtonTapAction: ((Any) -> Void)?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
        
        
      
    }
    
    @IBAction func clickBtnAct(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myButtonTapAction?(self)
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is my CellForTabelView Class

```
import UIKit

class CellForTableView: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOut: UICollectionView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: add table view cell index variable in your collectionview and when your going to add it your table view cell.. pass the index of current table cell.. then you can use it in your collection view cell.

Comment: Can you give me example with code? I'm begging in swift

Comment: @MohammedGomaa Please Give me an example. Because I'm beginner in swift

Comment: Sure dear, Please share CellForTableView class as well and I will reply to you instantly.

Comment: @MohammedGomaa Please check updated Question.

Comment: @MohammedGomaa ! I humbly request to Solve this problem. I searched the solution past two days.

Comment: Please find my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added tableview in a viewcontroller, then In tableViewCell I have managed the collectionView .. Updated my answer to show you same expected result in alert controller

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SampleTable
//
//  Created by Mohammed Gomaa on 7/8/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Mohammed Gomaa. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let arryOfTableCell = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self 
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arryOfTableCell.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell") as! CellForTableView
        cell.tableCellIndexPath = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
}

class CellForCollectionView: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var tableCellIndex: Int = 0
    var collectionCellIndex: Int = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

     @IBAction func clickBtnAct(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You Got it !", message: "Selected Collection Index is :\(collectionCellIndex) ,, Selected Table Index is :\(tableCellIndex)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

class CellForTableView: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let arryOfCollectionCell = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
var tableCellIndexPath = 0
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arryOfCollectionCell.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CellForCollectionView
    cell.tableCellIndex = self.tableCellIndexPath
    cell.collectionCellIndex = indexPath.row
    cell.button.setTitle("t:\(self.tableCellIndexPath), c:\(indexPath.row)", for: .normal)
    return cell
}
}

extension UIView {
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if parentResponder is UIViewController {
            return parentResponder as? UIViewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Gomma I don't know how to thanks. You saved my life and time. Thanks you so much. Allah Bless you.

Comment: Most welcome dear, Also tagging solution which provided by @Abu UI Hassan can be simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set tableViewCell index as tag of collectionView in willDisplayCell and can get it back in cellForItemAt delegate method

**add** `tableViewCell.collectionViewOut.tag = indexPath.row` in `willDisplayCell`

```
private func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? CellForTableView else { return }
        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)
tableViewCell.collectionViewOut.tag = indexPath.row
          
    }
```

and replace

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
     
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CellForCollectionView
        
        cell.myButtonTapAction = { cell in

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You Got it !", message: "Selected Index Path Number is \(indexPath[1]), tableCellIndex:\(collectionView.tag)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        
        return cell
    }
```